# Does Hinduism acknowledge the existence of other religions?

Tags: scripture, other-religions, christianity, islam

Hinduism isn't a religion but a way of living. Koran and Bible both mention Hinduism, Islam and Christianity and treat Hinduism and themselves as a religion but nowhere in a Hindu text Hinduism is considered a religion (at least not in my knowledge).

Is there any mention of other religions in any Hindu text?

Comment: This question is irrelevant. Hindu texts were written 4000 - 5000 years back, some even further back in time , dated before the times Islam, and Christianity were even defined or known. You can close this question itself.

Comment: I do not think the question is irrelevant. The question does not refer to major religions only

Comment: Where does the Bible mention Hinduism or Islam?

Comment: Yes. Hinduism does acknowledge the presence of other religions. In most of the cases, they are considered as foreigners. But there were people belonging to other communities in ancient India as well. In ancient India, majority was Hinduism. The story of the god Ayyappan(Sabari mala, Kerala) can be used as an example. Lord Ayyappan was born to kill Mahishi. There are stories that Manikandan(Ayyappan), during his school days, had a friend belonging to the Christian community. His name was Sebastianus. I think there is a church for him.

Comment: The term "Hindu" is geographical, so "Hinduism" is a geographical term referring to almost every different religion in India (besides Jainism and Buddhism). Thus we see it is an error to use the term "Hinduism", just the same as using the term "European" or "Asian". In reality there are many different forms of "Hinduism" since there are many different Indian religions, there are forms of Hinduism that are polytheistic, monotheistic, impersonalistic, those involving rituals, those involving no rituals, etc...but they are all labeled as "Hinduism".

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No. Hinduism or more properly Sanathana Dharma predates mature religions which are well known today. Also, Hinduism evolved as a way of living or culture as opposed to a strict set of rules enforced by a religious/political/other influential body hence there is no need to compare or take examples from other religions.

The scriptures focus on stories (historical or folklore) to serve as examples for human living of what is right or wrong.There may be other old religions which do not refer any other. Religions that evolved much later, like the ones you mentioned draw inspiration from the Hindu or other older religions or were inclined to go against a certain set of cultural values based on their own beliefs and experiences, hence the mention or comparison.

While the scriptures don't mention any other religions, they also do not reject any form of worship and has several examples (Kannappa Nayanar) where standard practices are overridden and Bhakti (devotion) is highlighted instead. This is quite an unique and important aspect of Hinduism

Comment: This answer says otherwise: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/148/86

Comment: Can you provide a source for your claim that "other religions did not exist in the immediate region"? This seems implausible, but I am happy to be convinced otherwise.

Comment: @BlueFlame that answer says the versions of Bhavishya Purana suggests discrepancies

Comment: @senshin I guess I got carried away. My mistake. I will correct it now, though I do not really know otherwise. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @LVS, Technically, Hindu texts span a timescale of at least 7000 years. In the initial years (Vedas and Upanishad), there were no mention of 'other' religion. Later on, after Buddhism 'forked' from Hinduism, you find mention of Buddhism in various commentaries and treatises. At a later stage, you will find mention of Islam and Christianity.

Answer (score 5):

Hinduism is not really a religion. Its a tradition n culture that people of India have been following for so long. Let me describe how Hinduism got its name:

When Muslims came to India they started calling people of India as Hindu because they first met Indians at the HIND RIVER. With time the non-Muslims started thinking of them self as Hindus (which does not meant religion but they started believing it).

The actual meaning of Hindu means Indian or even to be more accurate those who live beside HIND RIVER.

Comment: Where is HIND river? Please provide reference in your answers.

Comment: Please see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indus_River#Etymology_and_names which traces the origin to Sanskrit word "Sindhu"

Comment: Sindhu became Hindu and Indus became India.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there any mention of other religions in any Hindu text?

Yes, there is. In Veda itself there is a mantra that talks of people living on earth and speaking a variety of languages and having various religions.

The following mantra , found in the Atharva Veda, is a prayer to the all-supporting Earth, who supports everyone irrespective of the language they speak and the religion they follow.

> Janam vibhrati vahudhA vivAchas (1) **NAnAdharmAn prithvi** (2) YathA
>   okasam (3) Sahasram dhArA dravinasya me duhAm (4) Dhruveva dhenuh
>   anapasphuranti (5)
>
> .............
>
> Earth has people who speak various tongues (1) **and those who have
>   various religions** (2), according to their places of abode (3). [ May
>   she, the Earth] pour for me treasures in a thousand streams (4), like
>   a constant Cow that never fails.
>
> **Atharva Veda 12.1.45**

Note that, the mantra also mentions that religion will vary according to the places of abodes.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with K.Raghunathan , that since the Hindu Religious Texts were written at least 3000 years back ,there is no mention of other Religions , including Buddhsm . 
 Later day Saints like Guru Nanak ,Sant Kabir, Ramakrishna , Sai Baba of Siridi ,do make reference to other religions. 
 Sant Kabir & Saibaba of Siridi allowed both Hindus and Muslims to be their disciples. 
 Ramakrishna had teachers from Christianity and Islam for Spiritual Realisation. 
 All these teachers say that GOD is ONE ---but there are different ways of reaching Him .God is compared to the Ocean and the religions to various Rivers that are moving & trying to reach the Ocean. 
 Violence and Bloodshed , in trying to popularising one's beliefs , should be avoided .That comes out as the common theme of the preaching of these Saints.

Comment: K.Raghunathan? Do you mean @Raghuraman.K who made the [first comment](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/110/does-hinduism-acknowledge-the-existence-of-other-religions/10197#comment3944_110) under the question?