# Did Hindu scriptures predict Muhammad and/or Jesus?

Tags: scripture, puranas, other-religions, christianity, islam

There are some claims that ancient Hindu scriptures have mentioned Jesus Christ or the Prophet Muhammad.

- [BBC - "Hinduism: Jesus in Hinduism"](http://www.bbc.co.uk/religion/religions/hinduism/beliefs/jesus_1.shtml)
- ["Prophet Muhammad (pbuh) in Hindu scriptures" at Islam101](http://www.islam101.com/religions/hinduism/Mhs.htm)

I would like to know what is the stance of Hindu experts on these claims? Does the Hindu consensus accept that the *Bhavishya Purana* had "predicted" the Prophet Muhammad?

Comment: Jesus in India/Hinduism & Mohammad in Vedas is just a hoax created by Christians & Muslims in an effort to convert Hindus.

Comment: @RBK I agree such things are no more than hoaxes but whatever the motivations of those propagating such nonsense is, it seems "to convert Hindus" would be low on the list. Usually I see it being done to discredit Christianity / promote Hinduism. In any event anything Hindus would be converted to with hoaxes like that would not be Christianity as Christianity nearly universally rejects such suggestions and fabrications, not history.

Comment: @Caleb Go ahead, live like an ostrich if you wish. This is what they call 'inculturation' where the church mimics the native culture and shows as if Christianity is same as Hinduism and jesus is just another deity. But when the people are in, they slowly remove the native elements and the pure Christian identity in engineered and they are made to hate 'idols' &  'polytheists'. I have lived in a state where rabid proselytization is happening and this is what I have seen with my very own eyes.

Comment: @Bharat, for me its difficult to be called as a complete hoax, eg. The link of muhammad is a wrongly translated one, http://wikiislam.net/wiki/Bhavishya_Purana, why would a muslim preach such thing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is Jesus an avatar of Lord Vishnu?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2237/is-jesus-an-avatar-of-lord-vishnu)

Comment: @Bharat The Bhaviṣya Purāṇa is affirmed in the Padma Purāṇa to be a Mahāpurāṇa, putting above even celebrated texts like the Devī Bhāgavata. There is no scriptural reason not to believe in it, especially as the people who refute it clearly have not read it as they are unaware of: 1. The very obvious appearance of Gabriel  2. Christianity and Islam are each refrenced twice in the Khand, not once each. Read the scripture before refuting it for no reason

Comment: @AupakaranaAbhibhaa The original is

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The Bhavishya Purana is one of those scriptures which is not available in its authentic form. There isn't a single manuscript available now.

It has been altered and modified by so many people to suit their needs that now, it's nothing more than a couple of Sanskrit slokas. Stephen Knapp describes it best:

> However, I should also point out that this prophecy of Jesus in the *Bhavishya Purana* is found in no other *Puranas*, which often corroborate each other. This is why a study of the 18 major *Puranas* will reveal an assortment of prophecies that are often repeated one in another. So to find this story of Isha Mashiha in no other *Purana* sends a red flag of warning. Furthermore, not everyone gives the *Bhavishya Purana* pure confidence. It is known that as many as 200 pages from this text had become lost or misplaced, and various interpolations are likely to have occurred in this text while India was under the British administration. So, we should be somewhat cautious about accepting this on face value.

Moreover,

> However, there are presently four known editions of the *Bhavishya Purana*, each having different predictions from the other, but suspiciously having one consistent prediction - that of Jesus or Isha Masiha. One edition contains five chapters, one contains four, another contains three and yet another contains only two. Additionally, the contents in all four editions differ in various degrees - some having extra verses and some having less. Due to these circumstances, it is difficult to ascertain which of the four is the original text of the *Bhavishya Purana*, if indeed an original text still exists, but suspiciously, as mentioned, all four editions do mention Jesus.
>
> The Venkateswar Steam Press edition of the *Bhavishya Purana* printed in Bombay in 1829 (and reprinted by Nag Publishers in 2003) is probably the most complete version available, containing all the main features of the four manuscripts. Since **none** of the four editions of the *Bhavishya Purana* predate British Rule in India, this further suggests a discrepancy. The fact is that the British tried to **monopolize the publishing of all Sanskrit literature** during the British Raj. They bought or confiscated any Sanskrit literature they could locate. And that is why you practically cannot find any Vedic literature that is published before 200 years ago. It is further known that they liked to publish their own translations, as if India could not produce its own Sanskrit scholars to translate the Sanskrit themselves. Plus, they would also try to interpolate various verses here and there to have the reader draw a different conclusion of the personality or traits of the characters described in the texts. Most were quite noble, but by slipping in verses that said certain persons had less than admirable qualities or degraded habits, or that questionable practices were used, it would change the reader’s disposition and attitude toward such personalities or the Vedic culture itself, even if they were Indian born followers of it.
>
> Therefore, the consistent prophecy of Jesus in all four editions of the *Bhavishya Purana*, in spite of the differences in the editions found, seems to indicate an interpolation regarding the so-called meeting of Maharaja Shalivahana and Jesus. This is found in the 19th chapter of the Pratisarga-parva. However, as B. V. Giri Swami relates, in examining this section, certain flaws can be found which betray its dubious origins.

(bolding added)

So, basically it looks like a cooked up story with motives unknown. The complete article is ["Jesus Predicted in the Vedic Literature?"](http://www.stephen-knapp.com/jesus_predicted_in_the_vedic_literature.htm).

Comment: Interesting. I did not know there were 4 editions of Bhavishya Purana. Thanks!

Comment: Motives isn't completely unknown. It's part of the 'inculturation' effort by the Christian church to proselytize savage heathens(Hindus).

Comment: @RBK, I was just being politically correct. :P

Comment: @Bharat if jesus or Mohammed are mentioned in Hindu scriptures, doesn't that make hinduism "superior" in a way???

Comment: @imlokesh, it also makes conversion *more acceptable* to native Hindus to Islam or Christianity because then Jesus/Mohammed becomes acceptable figures in Hinduism. It also helps in misappropriation of Hindu cultural symbols

Comment: @imlokesh, No. We should understand the claims of Islam. Islam recognizes Jewish prophets as well as Jesus, the Christian prophet. Does this mean Muslims will accept Judaism as 'superior'. Not at all. According to Islam, it's predecessors(Jewsish, Christian prophets) were okay but not fully right/fully complete. Thus Islam is final, finalized & perfected, hence superior. Same applies to Hinduism. Still Islam would claim superiority as it is the final 'revelation'. Same case with Christianity too.

Comment: @imlokesh The Bhaviṣya Purāṇa is affirmed in the Padma Purāṇa to be a Mahāpurāṇa, putting above even celebrated texts like the Devī Bhāgavata. There is no scriptural reason not to believe in it, especially as the people who refute it clearly have not read it as they are unaware of: 1. The very obvious appearance of Gabriel 2. Christianity and Islam are each referenced twice in the Khand, not once each. Read the scripture before refuting it for no reason or find the words of someone who has.

Answer (score 7):

The fundamental difference between Western religions and Hinduism is the fact that Hinduism does not try to prove that God exists through references to Miracles, Predictions of the future etc.

Hindu texts prevail only on Understanding the Self. Realization of the truth. Texts and scriptures give knowledge bases to aid that understanding.  The concept of God itself is very simple, and complex at the same time. People who want to practice the Simple version do that, and people who want to practice the complex version do that as well.

But to believe in the concept of God, and the scriptures, forecasting, predictions etc are not really required. It is only required to aid people fall into the line. Hinduism never believed in proselytizing anyway.

Comment: Though I understand what you are saying in spirit, but from what I know, miracles are very much part of Hindu tradition/culture. For example, Lord Krishna has many stories about the miracles, ( which allude/reaffirm  that he is a God)

Comment: @san1646, true Krishna did perform miracles. BUT his miracles are not necessary condition for Hinduism to exist. There are various schools which don't depend on miracles of 1 man unlike Christianity which would collapse if Jesus's miracles were falsified.

Comment: Miracles just shows the power of mind, and Hindus believe in that power. All power is within you, you can do anything and everything. -Swami Vivekanada. So you too can do what we call 'miracle'.

Comment: I see this confusion as to what constitutes religious text in Hinduism. My opinion is that the Vedas, Upanishads, Bhagavat Gita and probably a couple of more texts would define the core. Then there are Puranas, then there are Epics, and then there are philosophical thesis like Advaita, Dwaita, then there are philosophical thesis by Wise men like Ramakrishna Paramahamsa, Vivekananda. There are so many levels. I try to answer questions from Vedic texts only. If you consider the rest, pretty much everything in our wildest imagination has been told, and retold.

Comment: Thank you.  Additional perspectives regarding miracles, simplicity... helped.

Comment: This is NOT an answer to the question!

Comment: @tempusfugit those are not miracles, they mere misinterpretation or yogic power. Anyone can achieve yogic power, if they follow the proper instructions. On the other hand miracles are exclusive and only performed by special character in history. Everyone can't turn water into wine.

Comment: @tempusfugit Thank you for remaining calm regarding this liberal pseudo-Hindus. While miracles are a part of the Hindu faith in the sense as you stated it is not an integral part of most of the six Darshanas. For example, Nyaya, Yoga, Vaisheshika, Samkhya and Minamsa don't have god as an integral part. God only matters in Dvaiata and Vishistadvaita where we see more theistic Abrahamic-like elements. Which is completely fine in my opinion.