# Is anything available in hinduism history about the incident of karbala?

Tags: history, islam

I have seen many Hindus who call themselves as *hussaini brahmins* who worship *Imam hussain* and his 72 companions.

So is the incident of *Karbala* present in any historical books of Hindus?

The thing is that I recently met a person who was working on this topic (Hinduism and *Karbala*). He gave me an article which was based on a Holy book of Hindus which was based on life history of lord Shiva and His wife Parvathi.

The lines were somewhat like this:

> Never forget Parvathi, after a long time from now there will be a pious boon of god who will be known by the name mahamat [prophet mohammed p.b.u.h.] who will have a beautiful daughter who will never commit any sin in her life [fatimah(s.a.)] but at last the disbelievers of mahamat kill her son very far away from his home without food water and shelter very brutally but after this humanity will open the eyes of everyone and that sacrifice shall be remembered till the end

Answer (score 6):

No authentic vedic text ever talks about Mohammad.

This reference to Mahamada is found only in Bhavishya Purana which itself is a very dubious text. It also speaks about Jesus and British rule. Refer to my answer for [Is Jesus avatar of lord Vishnu?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/2322/14) where I point out the dubious nature of Bhavishya Purana.

Refer to this article [Prophet Mohammed: Is He Really Predicted in the
Bhavishya Purana?](http://www.stephen-knapp.com/mohammed_is_he_really_predicted_in_bhavishya_purana.htm) which provides detailed rebuttal to Mohammed in Hinduism hoaxes and shows logical loopholes in those hoaxes.

Answer (score 0):

I came across [this post](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/8095/%E0%A4%AE%E0%A4%B9%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%AE%E0%A4%A6-is-not-islamic-muhammad-its-a-sanskrit-word-and-it-has-its-own-meaning) regarding mention of prophet in Hindu texts. The person have provided explanation to misconceived texts.