# महामद is not Islamic Muhammad, its a Sanskrit word and it has its own meaning?

Tags: scripture, other-religions, bhavishya-purana, islam, truth

I visited many of non Hindu sites that they argue that Prophet Muhammad is mentioned in our(Hindu) scriptures and they mention some sloka , I find one sloka in Bhavishya  Purana that they mention [image: BHavishya]

in above image and sloka line is महामद  इति  ख्यात:

they mention महामद as Prophet Muhammad but महामद is a Sanskrit word with its own meaning like

> महामद   mahAmada    m.  elephant in strong rut   मजबूत लीक में हाथी
>     महामद   mahAmada    m.  excessive or violent rut    अत्यधिक या हिंसक लीक
>     महामद   mahAmada    m.  fever       महामद   mahAmada    m.  great pride or
>   intoxication(drunkenness)  means मादकता  and  नशा

[महामद](http://spokensanskrit.de/index.php?tinput=mahAmada&script=&direction=SE&link=yes)

ख्यात:  meaning

> ख्यात   khyAta  adj.    denominated नामित
>
> ख्यात   khyAta  adj.    told    कहा था
>     ख्यात   khyAta  adj.    well known  अच्छी तरह से जाना जाता है
>     ख्यात   khyAta  adj. ppp.   called  कहा जाता है
>     ख्यात   khyAta  adj. ppp.   celebrated   मशहूर
>     ख्यात   khyAta  adj. ppp.   notorious   कुख्यात
>     ख्यात   khyAta  adj. ppp.   well-known  रूढ़
>     ख्यात   khyAta  adj. ppp.   named नामित

[ख्यात](http://spokensanskrit.de/index.php?tinput=khyAta&direction=SE&link=yes&choice=yes)

महामद  इति  ख्यात: means who ()well known or called) as drunkenness (intoxication) or many other above describe meaning and it's not talking about prophet Muhammad!  It is talking  about mleccha म्लेच्छ

mleccha म्लेच्छ has own meaning

> म्लेच्छ   mleccha m.  man of an outcast race  एक निर्वासित जाति का आदमी
>   म्लेच्छ   mleccha m.  person who does not speak Sanskrit   संस्कृत बात
>   नहीं   करता जो व्यक्ति    म्लेच्छ mleccha m.  foreigner   अन्यदेशीय
>   म्लेच्छ   mleccha m.  barbarian   असभ्य   & जंगली , अशिष्ट, गँवारू,
>   असंस्कृत      म्लेच्छ mleccha m.  non-Aryan   गैर आर्यन
>   म्लेच्छ   mleccha m.  ignorance of Sanskrit संस्कृत की अज्ञानता   who
>   does not know Sanskrit

[म्लेच्छ](http://spokensanskrit.de/index.php?script=HK&beginning=0+&tinput=mleccha&trans=Translate&direction=AU) means who does not know Sanskrit  or barbarian (असभ्य   & जंगली , अशिष्ट, गँवारू, असंस्कृत) etc.. and  धर्म  means manner or nature ,that time no other religious exist    so धर्म

> धर्म   dharma  m.  manner
>   धर्म   dharma  m.  nature

[धर्म](http://spokensanskrit.de/index.php?script=HK&beginning=0+&tinput=dharma+&trans=Translate&direction=AU) so,  म्लेच्छधर्म    means  barbarian manner or nature , अन्यदेशीय धर्म  , जंगली nature (swabhav)  etc above describe

So my question is why other religions(islam) argue that prophet Muhammad is in our scriptures ?

Comment: Well, you already have answered your question. But to sum it all, 1. They don't have good knowledge of Sanskrit and our religious scriptures. 2. They try to prove their superiority which in turn proves their insecurity and stupidity. 3. Because God is one and people keep fighting amongst themselves that "their" God is the best.

Comment: You should split the answer part into an answer below.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking what other religions deal with Hindu text which is not within the scope. Also it's welcoming opinions by asking "why other religion argue.." Apart from it, regarding the Sanskrit term, the question answers itself in the body of question.

Comment: This seems to be an interpolated part of the Bhavishya Purana.

Answer (score 2):

yes it is mention in "Bhavishya Purana " @UPASARGA Adhaya . Mahamad is "A-SUR "( Devil) re born Demon of " Tripura sur ".

Mahamad Captured " Shivalaya " of " Marusthalya " , Raja Boj Visited Marusthala ( Place in Desert ) .But GOD Shiva told him " Instead to escape " Shivalaya " from Devil Mohamada , take care of " Maha Kalyashwara " .

Marusthala is now "A-Pavitra " ( non worshiped place ).

As per "Bhavishya Purana " and " Muslim Quaran" this place ( Mah-KKa or Mecca )will be free by Hindu King in 2000 yrs as per Hijari Calendar and the war is mention - name - " Gazwa-e-Hind " ( End of Hindustan i.e. killing of hindus and captured land of india )

Comment: Welcome To Hinduism SE! Pls.provide some links to this  "Bhavishya Purana"  quoting in your answer to further support your claim.

Comment: Could you quote exact verses? your answer is unclear. Make edits accordingly.