# Correct translation of Prati Sarga: Part III, 3.3.5-27 of Bhavishya Purana

Tags: puranas, translation-request, islam, bhavishya-purana

Using these verses, Muslims often say Muhammad is predicted in Hindu scriptures. I provide Roman transliteration for all of the verses:

> mahamadh ithi khayat, shishya-sakha-samniviyath 5
>
> mahadev marusthal
>   nivasinam  mahadevthe snanya-pya punch-gavua samnivithya 6
>
> tripurarsur-nashav bahu-maya pravathiney 7
>
> malech-dharma shav shudhaya sat-chit-anandaya swarupye thva ma hei
>   kinkare vidhii sharanaghatham 8
>
> suta uvacha:
>
> ithi shurthiya sthav deva shabadh-mah nupaya tam, gath-vaya
>   bhojraj-ney mahakhaleshwar-sthale 9
>
> malech-shu dhushita bhumi-vahika nam-vishritha arya dharma hi
>   nav-vathra vahike desh-darunya 10
>
> vamu-vatra maha-mayi yo-sav dagdho myaa pura tripuro bali-daithyane
>   proshith punaragath 11
>
> ayoni sa varo math prasava daithyo-vrudhan  mahamadh ithi khayath ,
>   paishacha-kruthi thathpar 12
>
> nagathvaya thvya bhup paisachae desh-vartake math prasadhayane bhupal
>   tav shudhii prajayathe 13
>
> thi shruthva nupshav svadesha-napu maragmath  mahamadh toi sdhav
>   sindhu-thir mupaye-yav 14
>
> uchav bhupati premane mahamadh-virshad tva deva maharaja das-tva
>   magath 15
>
> mamo-chit sabhu jiya-dhatha tatpashya bho nup ithi shruthya ththa hata
>   para vismaya-magath 16
>
> malechdhano mathi-shasi-tatsaya bhupasaya darutho 17
>
> tucha tva kalidas-sthu rusha praah mahamadham maya-thei nirmithi
>   dhutharya nush-mohan-hethvei 18
>
> hanishyami-duravara vahik purusha-dhamum ityak va sa jidh
>   shrimanava-raja-tathpar 19
>
> japthya dush-sah-trayach tah-sahansh juhav sa bhasm mutva sa mayavi
>   malech-dev-tva-magath 20
>
> maybhithashtu tachya-shyaa desh vahii-kamayuuah guhitva svaguro-bhasm
>   madaheen tva-magatham 21
>
> swapiit tav bhu-ghyot-thro-shrumadh-tathpara madaheen puro jath thosha
>   trith sayam smurthaum 22
>
> rathri sa dev-roop-shav bahu-maya-virshad paisacha deha-marathaya
>   bhojraj hi so trivith 23
>
> arya-dharmo hei to raja-sarvoutham smurth ishapraya karinayami
>   paishacha dharma darunbhu 24
>
> linga-chedri shikhaheen shamshu dhaari sa dhushak yukhalapi sarva
>   bhakshi bhavishyat jano maum 25
>
> vina kaul cha pashav-thosha bhakshava matha maum muslanav sanskar
>   kushariv bhavishyat 26
>
> tasman-musal-vanto hi jathiyo dharma dhushika ithi pishacha-dharma mya
>   kruth 27

English translation of Bhavishya Purana is not available online. Some say this verses mean Muhammad was a reincarnation of a demon. But, in [this](https://bhavishyapuran.wordpress.com/) website, the author argued that it was due to mistranslation.

Comment: Related [महामद is not Islamic Muhammad, its a Sanskrit word and it has its own meaning?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/8095/3500)

Comment: @TheDestroyer why in Vedas gods are considered as asuras in many verses?