# Is Prophet Muhhamad mentioned in the Bhavishya Puran? If he is mentioned is he presented as good or evil?

Tags: bhavishya-purana

I am really confused about this, please help me!

Comment: Not really, please look at https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/8095/%E0%A4%AE%E0%A4%B9%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%AE%E0%A4%A6-is-not-islamic-muhammad-its-a-sanskrit-word-and-it-has-its-own-meaning