# Is Lord Krishna "The Father of Universe" as revealed by Jesus Christ?

Tags: krishna

Jesus Christ always considered himself as the son of God - "The Father of Universe". In Gita Bhagavat, Lord Krishna revealed himself - "The Father of All Kinds and Beings" throughout the conversation with Arjun at War.

So, my question here - "Is Lord Krishna "The Father of Universe" as revealed by Jesus Christ?" Or, Lord Krishna is the indication as mentioned by Jesus Christ. Please clarify the connection if any one has valid answer.

Comment: Related [Is Jesus avatar of lord Vishnu?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2237/is-jesus-avatar-of-lord-vishnu)

Comment: This seems far too speculative for the site, so I'm closing your question.

Comment: Good question sir. Jesus Christ said that He was the son of God. But He also later said I and my Father are One. He also said that no-one comes to the Father but through Me. In the book, the Second Coming of Christ, by Sri Swami Paramhansa Yogananda, He says that Father implies the impersonal Absolute Nirguna Brahman. The God without qualities. Jesus is that God with qualities. He is personal, has a name and a form. Thus He says that He is the son of God, in the sense that He has come from that impersonal Absolute God. At the same time, He is not different from that God. All the best sir.