# Origin and location of Mleccha tribes in Mahabharatha

Tags: puranas, bhagavata-purana, bhavishya-purana

The questions related to the title are multifold as follows,

1. In [this](http://www.bhakticharuswami.com/2014/01/05/the-origin-of-western-religions) article the late Suhotra Swami quotes Bhavishya Purana saying that Mlecchas are descended from Adama and Havyavathi who are children of Rishi Kardama. Are the above claims about [Mlecchas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mleccha) and their religion and lineage of prophets prophets really present in the Bhavishya Purana? Is there a authentic verison of this Purana available online?
2. Is there any other Purana which talks about the origins of Mlecchas and about Adama, Havayavathi lineage? Does Bhagavata Purana or Mahabharatha has references to the same?
3. In the Mahabharatha, many Mleccha tribes are mentioned like  Sakas, Huns, Yavanas(Greek), Kambojas, Pahlavas, Bahlikas, Rishikas, [Chinas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinas)(China), etc, etc. Are connections made to Greeks, Syrians, Chinese, etc mere conjecture or has the Mahabharatha mentioned any Capital cities, traditions, languages or practices which directly like these Mleccha tribes to the present day nation states?

[Here] is an (http://hindudharma.quora.com/Rarely-known-secrets-about-Hinduism) interesting read on this regard which prompted some of the above question.

Comment: The Bhavishya Purana in its current form has many interpolations; see Bharat's answer here: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/2322/36 This Adama and Havyavathi business is just an attempt to incorporate the Christian idea of Adam and Eve into Hinduism.  In any case, the Srimad Bhagavatam only mentions one child of Kardama, and that is Vishnu's incarnation Kapila: http://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/3/24

Comment: Correction: Kardama actually had nine daughters, but Kapila was his only son; see the family tree here: http://vedadev.ru/images/SB%20Family%20Tree03.jpg

Comment: Is Havyavathi one of the nine daughters? Also anything on the origin/progenitor of Mlecchas?

Comment: No, Kardama's nine daughters were named Kala, Anasuya, Shraddha, Havirbhu, Gati, Kriya, Khyati, Arundhati, and Shanti, and they were married to Marichi, Atri, Angiras, Pulastya, Pulaha, Kratu, Bhrigu, Vasishta, and Atharva; see verses 22, 23, and 24 of this Srimad Bhagavatam chapter: http://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/3/24 So there was no daughter named Havyavati and no one married to anyone named Adama.

Comment: The Adi Parva of the Mahabharata says that the Mlecchas and Yavanas are descendants of Yayati: http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01086.htm "The sons of Yadu are known by the name of the Yadavas: while those of Turvasu have come to be called the Yavanas. And the sons of Drahyu are the Bhojas, while those of Anu, the Mlechchhas. The progeny of Puru, however, are the Pauravas."