# Scriptural mention of places other than India?

Tags: mahabharata, vedas, ramayana, puranas, history

Besides the Indian subcontinent, are there any Puranic or Vedic references or mention of other places on Earth? I know about Sri Lanka mentioned in Ramayana. But other than Lanka and India, what do our ancient scriptures say about the rest of the world?

Comment: I am not sure but I think Sri Lanka and Japan qualifies

Comment: @AngelusMortis What reference to Japan are you referring to?

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hinduism_in_Japan

Comment: @AngelusMortis That article doesn't mention any scriptural references to Japan.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan is it mergeable with [Original location of Mleccha tribes in Mahabharata](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/7469/1049)? Also related to [Were Yavanas Greeks or Egyptians](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/11208/1049).

Comment: @iammilind No, I don't think it's a duplicate - that question is about the location of various races.  This is a more general question about what Hindu scriptures say about the rest of the world.