# Why and how do Hindus celebrate Christmas?

Tags: culture, tradition, other-religions, christianity

Why and how do (some) Hindus celebrate Christmas?

What have any modern Hindu Gurus commented on this practice?

---

**EDIT**

<sub>I don't think this is an opinion-based question. From [*What types of questions should I avoid asking?*](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) I think this fits into constructive subjective questions: "inspire answers that explain **why** and **how**"</sub>

Comment: 1.That is the practice which became popular after the entry of catholic schools into the country. 2. Effect of secularism on the minds of younger generation. 3. Effect of hollywood movies and internet.

Comment: You can remove "why" part. As purely Christmas is non Hindu festival, "why" is primarly opinion based.

Comment: Yeshua wasn't even born on 25th December. The Bible's description of the surroundings of his birth suggest he was born around September. 25th December used to celebrated as the Pagan Festivals of Saturnalia and Yule. But after the Roman Empire adopted Christianity, they decided to celebrate 25th December as Christmas.

Answer (score 6):

The Ramakrishna Mission celebrates Christmas with a puja. Ramakrishna Paramahamsa and Swami Vivekananda looked upon Jesus Christ as one of the incarnations of God. Most of the centers have some type of puja or recognition of Christmas as the celebration of Jesus's birth. See - http://media.belurmath.org/festival-calendar-of-belur-math-for-2016-17-634

Comment: Are you sure that they consider him as God? Because even Christianity doesn't consider him as God. He is well know as Son of God. Also, it is best to consider him as a saint. He was really a magnificent soul and saintly being.

Answer (score 5):

I think that **orthodox** Hindus do not celebrate Christmas.
... And that would mean that those Hindus who do celebrate Christmas are not orthodox Hindus.

- orthodox -- conforming to what is generally or traditionally accepted as right or true; established and approved; strictly keeping to traditional doctrine and ritual

Comment: Don't ISKCON people believe that Jesus is an Avesha Avatara of Vishnu?

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan haha, I knew you'd be bothered with that and ask something like that. Yes, ISKCON devotees take statement of Srila Prabhupada, actually it is said that his guru said that first, that Jesus is a Shaktyavesa avatara (especially empowered incarnation) to preach a religious principles as some derivative of the vedic religion. But I think that Gaudiya Vaishnavas prior to that time did not recognise Jesus as such. And although that issue seems to be typical for modern Gaudiyas, it was not typical for early Gaudiyas. So I'd say modern Gaudiyas are not orthodox on that point.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Thus it could be that some modern Gaudiyas do celebrate Christmas because they recognise Jesus as a Shaktyavesa avatara, and thus they want to show, let's say, some kind of respect or appreciation for his efforts to enlighten the people back than 2000 years ago. But I think this is not typical for Gaudiyas in general, and I'd say it's somewhat unorthodox. And even then, I'm sure, they do not celebrate Christmas with the same understanding as Christians do, for they perceive Jesus quite different.

Comment: 'orthodox' Hindus 1) believe in God 2) accept the vedas as the revealed word of God and 3) believe in cycles and reincarnation. All modern orthodox Hindus follow 1) the Gita 2) the Brahma Sutras and 3) the Upanishads. A person can accept Jesus as an incarnation and still be an orthodox Hindu...

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda Please see the definition of the word "orthodox" that I have posted above in my answer, that I took from the google translate dictionary at https://translate.google.com/ So, if an orthodox Hindu follows that what you said then you should be able to find some verses about Jesus and celebration of him in the Gita, Vedanta Sutras or Upanishads, and thus when you celebrate Jesus you would be an orthodox Hindu. But if you can't find verses about Jesus, but you still celebrate him, then you are not quite an orthodox Hindu. It's very simple. ...

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda ... I'm not saying that to celebrate Jesus is something bad, but I'm just saying that it's not quite an orthodox Hindu practice. And Hindu tradition is a proof of that because in the past centuries none of the acaryas has said anything about Jesus and celebrating him or Christmas.

Comment: @brahmajijnasa Except for Krishna in the Gita, there is no mention of any of the incarnations in the Upanishads or the Vedanta Sutras or the Gita. To see a better definition of 'Astika' - orthodox Hindu - see pages ii-iii in the 'Introduction' here -   http://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/brahma-sutras/d/doc62753.html

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda Well, my understanding of the word "orthodox" differs from the one in that book. My understanding goes along the lines of the dictionary definition that I quoted above. And according to that it's not quite an orthodox Hindu practice to celebrate Jesus or Christmas. I'm sure about that.

Comment: @brahmajijnasa astika and nastika are already defined for centuries by many Hindus scholars and brahmins without the help of a English dictionary

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda What I said above has nothing to do with the terms astika and nastika. I was talking about orthodox Hindu practice and unorthodox Hindu practice.

Comment: @brahmajijnasa There is no orthodox Hindu practice as you imply. The only thing orthodox about Hindu practices is the commonality of the way pujas are practiced.

Answer (score 3):

The Sri Sathya Sai Ashram celebrates Christmas every year in a grand manner. The previous evening usually comprises a program by an International Music Orchestra, that plays Christmas Carols. On Christmas Morning, (proper) Christians and other Hindu devotees from all over the world and India, go in a candle procession around the Ashram. Christmas evening sometimes has a play or cultural program on the life and message of Jesus Christ, or a music program by an international artist.

The Ashram is decorated colorfully with stars, lights etc. In the last few years, every year, a different country is given charge of the grand decoration activity. Devotees from that country decorate the ashram with volunteers.

When Sri Sathya Sai Baba was alive, he gave a discourse on Christmas every year, mentioning the good qualities to be learnt from Christ's life and his relationship with God. The celebrations every year, make hardly any distinction between Hindus residing Abroad/India and overseas citizens/born christians, in terms of participation. The activities often begin with a chant of Omkar and end with a chant of Samastha Loka Sukino Bhavanthu and Om Shanthi as on the other Hindu festival days.

http://www.srisathyasai.org.in/pages/ashraminfo/Christmas.htm

http://media.radiosai.org/journals/vol_13/01DEC15/Christmas-Celebrations-at-Prasanthi-Nilayam-2015.htm

Answer (score 2):

<sub>Actually, it's opinion based question. Because you won't be able to accept any answer as correct. However, the answers can be interesting. Hence leaving upto community, if it should be closed or not.</sub>

I am from a very specialized section of Hinduism:

> Hindu > Vaishnava > Krishna > Pre-tennage version (Bal swaroop) >
>   [ThAkorji / ShrinAthji](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shrinathji)

Though the family is very conservative, when it comes to Christmas, they are liberal. It's celebrated something like this:

[image]

**Why**. No single reason. Generally in India, I think English schooling has more to do with why people celebrate Christmas. Moreover, culturally we were influenced by the British. Many people believe Jesus as an incarnation of Vishnu as well & many don't. Source:
[Is Jesus an avatar of Lord Vishnu?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/2237/1049)

Answer (score 1):

I think Hinduism has a history of adopting foreign gods from a very early period. There is nothing wrong with this. The *saguna brahman* is inexhaustible and can therefore manifest in all sorts of ways. That is why it is an entirely orthodox Hindu practice to consider Jesus a manifestation of the Godhead.

Most Hindus who do celebrate Christmas do not celebrate it *like Christians do*. They use Hindu ritual idioms to do so. If any Hindu Acharya can be considered an avatar by his pupils and their descendants, why not do the same with Jesus Christ? After all, he is just another Bhakti Yoga teacher.

Shri Ramakrishna and Swami Vivekananda, for example, went quite far in the direction of integrating Jesus Christ into Hinduism (Hence the Christmas celebrations at Ramakrishna Maths)

Here are a few links: http://www.spiritualbee.com/posts/sri-ramakrishna-vision-of-jesus/
https://swamishivapadananda.typepad.com/swami_shivapadananda/2010/11/jesus-ramakrishna-and-avatars.html
https://vedanta.org/what-is-vedanta/the-avatar-god-in-human-form/

Comment: @Sarvabhouma but who defines what an "Orthodox Hindus" is? There is no central authority in Hinduism.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma I have added a few links to my original answer to show how widspread the idea of JC as a Hindu manifestation of the divine already is.

Comment: "That is why it is an **entirely orthodox Hindu practice** to consider Jesus a manifestation of the Godhead." How did you define what is an orthodox Hindu practice? Orthodox Hindu means who practices the religion and follows injunctions present in the Holy texts. There is definitely, a central authority in Hinduism. There are Swamijis and acharyas who following disciplinic tradition.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma: For example, considering Jesus Christ a manifestation of the Godhead is orthodox according to Advaita. In Advaita, there is no limited list of the forms _saguna Brahman_ can take. _saguna Brahman_ can manifest as Shiva or as Kartikeya or as Jesus Christ because, in any case, all these forms will be transcended, and thus discarded, when one realizes _nirguna Brahman_. It does not matter what _saguna Brahman_ form you worship since it is only a stepping stone towards _nirguna Brahman_. That is why many Vedantins, like Shri Ramakrishna or Swami Vivekananda were very open to it.

Comment: Well, Adi Shankaracharya condemned the worship of some demigods and goddesses in his Bhagavad Gita commentary. Everyone is not a manifestation of Saguna Brahman. Even he encouraged worshipping only six gods and goddesses. I take Adi Shankaracharya as orthodox. NoShankara mutt built churches. How are gods who were introduced a 1000 years and 300 years to us traditional and orthodox? That's a new addition. E.g I can't be Saguna Brahman if some starts worshipping me.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma: There were Christians in Kerala since 1500 years ago, i.e. before the birth of Adi Shankara. And yet he did not condemn the worship of Jesus Christ even though he was born in Kerala.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma: Shankara Mathas do not build shrines to Jesus Christ because it is not part of _their_ tradition. But Shankara Mathas tradition do not encompass the whole of Hinduism. They are only one part of it. As I said (and Swami Vishwananda in his answer above) Ramakrishna Mathas do honor Jesus Christ. Do you mean to say that they are not "orthodox"?