# Why does Ramakrishna Mission perform Jesus puja on Christmas?

Tags: ramakrishna

[image]

Watch this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wF4UYQresZQ). You can clearly see a monk of Ramakrishna order is performing the Hindu Ritual Puja. But instead of any Hindu deity, there is an image of Jesus. This 2018 video is from the Ramakrishna Mission, Delhi. They have started doing this in Belur Math also.

I am baffled! What is going on here?

- Is this the teaching of Sri Ramakrishna?
- Can they cite a single reference in the Hindu corpus where Jesus puja is mentioned?
- Did Ramakrishna himself ever perform Jesus Puja?
- Did the founder of the Mission, Swami Vivekananda, ever offer Puja to Jesus?

Comment: Shree Ramakrishna Paramhansa was never into other religions support, I have talked to some of the ardent followers to verify that. However their recent followers started disturbing the mission.

Comment: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/21287/did-ramakrishna-paramahamsa-accept-jesus-christ-as-the-begotten-son-of-god

Comment: @MrGreenGold I got this information from a follower that these all publications are false and are made to attract people, but has no real proof to support.

Comment: @MrGreenGold Uhm? I am not sure where this discussion is going. ^^

Comment: The concept of incarnations is not in the vedas, it occurs only in the puranas. To ascribe one person or another as an incarnation is a highly sectarian concept within ALL Hindu sects. If one sect does puja to Vishnu, the Shavites laugh. If Shavites do puja to Shiva, the Vashnavites laugh. Your question is meant to solicit opinions, please see the forum rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR: The answer to all your questions is No.

In his work ["Ramakrishna Mission - In Search of a New Identity" (1986)](https://archive.org/details/ramakrishna-mission-ram-swarup/page/9/mode/2up), Ram Swarup painstakingly sifted through historical records to refute claims of Ramakrishna embracing Islam and Christianity.

It is pertinent to point out that Ramakrishna's followers had taken upon themselves to reimage the Mission as "universal non-hindu" post the former's demise. But it gathered steam in 1980s when the Mission felt the need to identify itself as not a hindu religion in order to enjoy protection both from their staff as well as from the Marxist government in West Bengal. Institutions belonging to religious minorities are safe and their management secure from Government intervention, very unlike institutions run by Hindus which enjoy no such protection and which are subject to all kinds of interference from a Government.

They found intermediate success when High Court of West Bengal accepted their argument on being distinct from Hinduism -

> Arguing for the “distinct” existence of the Mission, the affidavit says that not all its members are Hindus and, in fact, some of them are Muslims and Christians. The first fact proves that it is non-sectarian, the second that it is universal. This is the pattern which the afhdavit faithfully observes-when the inclusiveness of the Mission is to be shown, Islam and Christianity are mentioned; when its distinct character is to be shown, Hinduism is mentioned. The Mission is distinct from Hinduism in some respects and similar to Islam and Christianity in others. That makes it unique and universal —that is the line of argument.

> The Mission also claims to be “unique” on the ground that its followers believe in the “universal brotherhood of all, irrespective of caste, creed, community, language and nationality.

However to to bolster their claim of a new identity they conjured Ramakrishna's image "as a practitioner of all religions"

> As regards Ramakrishna’s “practice of Islam and Christianity” of which the Mission makes so much, it finds **no mention in the *Gospel*, the earliest and most authentic** account of Ramakrishna’s thoughts and experiences in his own words. In this work we find that though Ramakrishna reminisces often about his experiences and God-filled states, there is hardly a word about his so-called practice of Islam and Christianity. It first finds place in Swami Saradanandas biography, “Sri Ramakrishna: The Great Master’, a devout work alright but not “untarnished by the writer's mind’, an eminent quality of the Gospel in the words of Vivekananda. The author had met Ramakrishna in the last two years of the latter’s life and the work itself was written 25 years after when an incipient theology of the Mission had already emerged and when the Mission was learning to look at its old master in the light of its future work as it conceived it.

Also from Saradanandas' work we learn that in a life devoted to intense Sadhana extending over many years, the so-called practice of Islam and Christianity occupied no more than three days.

> In November 1874, the practice of Christianity followed about the same course except that it involved not even this initial Sadhana. He had listened to some readings from the Bible (one wonders what portions) and he was moved. One day sitting in the parlour of a devotee, he saw a painting of the Madonna and the Child on the wall. Presently, Ramakrishna became ecstatic. The mood last for three days, at the end of which he saw a luminous figure appearing, entering into and merging with him. (The affidavit mentions this). This, Swami Saradananda calls the “Master’s vision of Sri Ish.”

Even if Saradananda's account, who met Ramakrishna only in his last 2 years and wrote his biography 25 years later, is accepted at face value , it in no way points to Christianity as an acceptable path. For an average Christian, image of "Ish" merging with Ramakrishna is undoubtedly an insult. Furthermore it is nothing unusual about Ramakrishna's visions of "Ish" from a Yogic viewpoint

> When one meditates on the object (Karmasthana), it undergoes several
> successive modifications. It gets internalized; it loses its
> blemishes; it assumes a luminous form (jyotishmati); it assumes a
> joyous form (visoka). All this is a normal process of yogic
> modification and ingestion. The same thing happened to the “thoughts”
> of Muhammad and Jesus when they passed through the cricible of
> Ramakrishna’s mind. **It need not give birth to an indiscriminate
> theology like the one produced by the Mission that all prophets and
> religions are equal and that they all say the same thing**

Answer (score 3):

Sri Ramakrishna had a spiritual experience of Christ that convinced him that Christ was an Incarnation. However, Ramakrishna's Jesus is not the Jesus of Christian faith. Ramakrishna rejected the Christian claim that Jesus is the only way.

> Eight years later, some time in November 1874, Sri Ramakrishna was
> seized with an irresistible desire to learn the truth of the Christian
> religion. He began to listen to readings from the Bible, by Sambhu
> Charan Mallick, a gentleman of Calcutta and a devotee of the Master.
> Sri Ramakrishna became fascinated by the life and teachings of Jesus.
> One day he was seated in the parlour of Jadu Mallick's garden house
> (This expression is used throughout to translate the Bengali word
> denoting a rich man's country house set in a garden.) at Dakshineswar,
> when his eyes became fixed on a painting of the Madonna and Child.
> Intently watching it, he became gradually overwhelmed with divine
> emotion. The figures in the picture took on life, and the rays of
> light emanating from them entered his soul. The effect of this
> experience was stronger than that of the vision of Mohammed. In dismay
> he cried out, "O Mother! What are You doing to me?" And, breaking
> through the barriers of creed and religion, he entered a new realm of
> ecstasy. Christ possessed his soul. For three days he did not set foot
> in the Kali temple. On the fourth day, in the afternoon, as he was
> walking in the Panchavati, he saw coming toward him a person with
> beautiful large eyes, serene countenance, and fair skin. As the two
> faced each other, a voice rang out in the depths of Sri Ramakrishna's
> soul: "Behold the Christ, who shed His heart's blood for the
> redemption of the world, who suffered a sea of anguish for love of
> men. It is He, the Master Yogi, who is in eternal union with God. It
> is Jesus, Love Incarnate." The Son of Man embraced the Son of the
> Divine Mother and merged in him. Sri Ramakrishna realized his identity
> with Christ, as he had already realized his identity with Kali, Rama,
> Hanuman, Radha, Krishna, Brahman, and Mohammed. The Master went into
> samadhi and communed with the Brahman with attributes. Thus he
> experienced the truth that Christianity, too, was a path leading to
> God-Consciousness. Till the last moment of his life he believed that
> Christ was an Incarnation of God. But Christ, for him, was not the
> only Incarnation; there were others — Buddha, for instance, and
> Krishna.

**The Gospel of Sri Ramakrishna, Introduction, translated by Swami Nikhilananda**

It has been mentioned that the above story is not genuine according to some people. So I am now posting a chat between Sri M and Sri Ramakrishna that confirms the above passage.

> M: "It is indeed difficult to understand that. One cannot quite grasp
> how God, Perfect Brahman that He is, can dwell in that small body."
>
> The Master quoted from a song:
>
> Oh, no one at all has found out who He is; Like a madman from door to
> door He roams, Like a poor beggar He roams from door to door.
>
> M: "**You also told us about Jesus**."
>
> MASTER: "What did I say?"
>
> M: "**You went into samadhi at the sight of Jesus Christ's picture in
> Jadu Mallick's garden house. You saw Jesus come down from the picture
> and merge in your body**."

**The Gospel of Sri Ramakrishna, Chapter 43, Visit to Nanda Bose's House**

Comment: "However, Ramakrishna's Jesus is not the Jesus of Christian faith". Just curious which Jesus is being worshipped by Ramkrishnaites today?

Comment: What I mean is that according to Christian faith Jesus is the only way. Ramakrishna did not accept that idea. This is what I mean by the statement that Ramakrishna's Jesus is not the Jesus of the Christian faith (who according to the Christian faith is the only way to salvation). Ramakrishna's Jesus is one particular way to moksha. There are other ways to attain moksha.

Comment: @AmritenduMukhopadhyay yes whenever a divine being happens a religion will be build around him. Like the Krishna of Ramakrishna, is he the Krishna of Isckonites??

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto this is the story

Comment: @MrGreenGold Similar to Mohammad vision this story is also scripted. That's what I learnt from one of the follower.

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto I don't which follower you are talking about. How is a random nameless follower more trustworthy than the official publication. Master Mahashaya or M who has written the dialogues has meticulously recorded his conversation directly from Ramakrishna Paramahamsa. If you can't trust him how can you trust this follower

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto also you can easily see what's Swami Vivekananda's opinion is. If anyone's an authority of what Ramakrishna Paramahamsa believed then it has to be Swami Vivekananda.

Comment: Not true that all Christians believe Jesus is the only way to God. And debatable whether “the Christian faith” says that. Christianity is more eclectic than some other religions. Many believe Jesus said to those he was talking to, then and there, saying He was the only way. Others believe He was speaking as the Christ or Universal Consciousness (the great I am) who was saying that, not the person of Jesus is but that the feet of the guru, universal consciousness, or “I am” is. If you are chanting I am Brahman and then say And I am the Only Way, who’s saying that? https://youtu.be/dgOzPb0hBOw

Answer (score 2):

Lord Kṛṣṇa said in Bhagavad Gita,

> ये यथा मां प्रपद्यन्ते तांस्तथैव भजाम्यहम् |
>  मम वर्त्मानुवर्तन्ते
> मनुष्या: पार्थ सर्वश: ||4:11||

> In whatever way people surrender unto me, I reciprocate/reward with them
> accordingly. Everyone follows My path, knowingly or unknowingly, O son
> of Pritha.

As a Kṛṣṇa devotee, neither do I complain about someone worshipping some manifested Godlike character, nor I appreciate it. I grew up near a Ramkrishna Mission temple and seen this incident recently as early as 5-6 years ago. I don't know why they do it but it is not mentioned in any of the religious scriptures.

*N.B. I am not a member of a follower of ISKCON or so. I just follow Bhagavad Gita as a spiritual guide.*

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand what's baffling in this. Modern Yogis of India starting with Ramakrishna Paramahamsa, Swami Vivekananda to Paramahamsa Yogananda, Swami Rama, Shri M, Sadhguru etc. have all considered Jesus as an enlightened master and a manifestation of divinity.

I have heard people saying the stories of Ramakrshna Paramahamsa practising Christianity is made up. I honestly don't know, but I guess there are many books published by Ramakrishna Ashrama itself which says these.

Also if anyone is an authority of Ramakrishna mission it's Swami Vivekananda. Please read the following and then decide yourself what Swamiji's opinion of Christ was.

> Jesus Christ was God — the Personal God become man. He has manifested
> Himself many times in different forms and these alone are what you can
> worship. God in His absolute nature is not to be worshipped.
> Worshipping such God would be nonsense. We have to worship Jesus
> Christ, the human manifestation, as God. You cannot worship anything
> higher than the manifestation of God. The sooner you give up the
> worship of God separate from Christ, the better for you [[Source]](https://en.m.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Complete_Works_of_Swami_Vivekananda/Volume_8/Notes_Of_Class_Talks_And_Lectures/The_Divine_Incarnation_Or_Avatara)

---

> If I, as an Oriental have to worship Jesus of Nazareth, there is only
> one way, that is, to worship him as God and nothing else. [[Source]](https://en.m.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Complete_Works_of_Swami_Vivekananda/Volume_4/Lectures_and_Discourses/Christ,_the_Messenger)

---

> Everything is the living God, the living Christ; see it as such.
> [[Source](https://en.m.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Complete_Works_of_Swami_Vivekananda/Volume_7/Inspired_Talks/Friday,_August_2)]

---

> Father is the existence out of which everything comes; Son is that
> knowledge. It is in Christ that God will be manifest. God was
> everywhere, in all beings, before Christ; but in Christ we became
> conscious of Him. This is God. The third is bliss, the Holy Spirit [[Source](https://en.m.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Complete_Works_of_Swami_Vivekananda/Volume_8/Notes_Of_Class_Talks_And_Lectures/The_Divine_Incarnation_Or_Avatara)]

---

> Had I lived in Palestine, in the days of Jesus of Nazareth, I would
> have washed his feet, not with my tears, but with my heart’s
> blood![[Source](https://en.m.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Complete_Works_of_Swami_Vivekananda/Volume_9/Sayings_and_Utterances)]

---

> I have come to deal with principles. I have only to preach that God
> comes again and again, and that He came in India as Krishna, Rama, and
> Buddha, and that He will come again. It can almost be demonstrated
> that after each 500 years the world sinks, and a tremendous spiritual
> wave comes, and on the top of the wave is a Christ.[Source](https://en.m.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Complete_Works_of_Swami_Vivekananda/Volume_8/Notes_Of_Class_Talks_And_Lectures/Notes_Of_Class_Talks)

---

In the last saying you can clearly see him comparing Jesus with Rama and Krishna and Buddha. Many Hindu Atheists question that why all the incarnations of God happen only in India. And when Krishna promised he will take birth whenever adharma increases, did he say it applies to only India?

No. But many people say Bharata is karma bhoomi so the incarnation happens only in India.

One can agree that most incarnations of God happen in India but to hold no incarnation of God happens outside India is simply going against the idea of Krishna in Gita. What will happen if Adharma increases in foreign lands? Ramakrishna mission people and many yogis believe that Jesus was one such incarnation of the divine.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127525/discussion-on-answer-by-mr-green-gold-why-does-ramakrishna-mission-perform-jesus).

Comment: If the bar is performing puja or other christian or christmas ceremony add swami vishwananda. If it is worhsipping and repeatedly referring to christ and the holy spirit then add Mooji too. If it is simply seeing christ as fully enlightened manifestation of God, as God, add Maharshi too: “[Christ was) a Jnani [who] has attained liberation even while alive, here and now. It is immaterial as to how, where and when he leaves his body”

Comment: Yes, I just took a few examples