# Can a non-Indian person trust Sanatan Dharma, follow it and so become Hindu?

Tags: dharma-shastras, manu-smriti

Preface:

I didn't find nowhere in the Shastras which I have read, nor in other books, if a person who was born inside a Western Country and feels devotion for Sanataan Dharma conducts of life, Devas and yog practices, can be truly regarded as Sanataani or Hindu by the Indians.

Comment: Sanatana Dharma is actually set of instructions to follow for well being but not a religion. Hindus follow this. Anyone can follow it. This is the reason we don't have religion conversion practices (there might be but it is just to make one feel bound to it). The one who don't follow might be known as Abrahamic (I am not sure about this but guessing that it should be the case).

Comment: Abrahmics are literally the believers of Abraham or Ibrahim ideas: the jews, the christians, the muslims. 2.000 years ago approximately it is narrated that a magician twisted and warped the Brahma and Maa Saraswaati names, in order to creat god-head on Earth: Abraham (called Ibrahim by the muslims) and his wife Sara. Other were not than simply humans who thought to be the special "people of God". Then we have history of Adam, Eve, the evil snake etc etc. Personally @Mr_Green I want to point out that I do not believe in the related teachings of Abrahmics to can find something evaluable.

Comment: Hence I feel the truths to be unveiled only through Sanataan Dharma. However Bhavishya Purana details explain how these magicians, leading with some Asuras and Pisachas, invented these religions. I would hint that Tripura Asura is involved into that. @Mr_Green I am looking for true Indian Hindu long time distant friends and it is crucial for me to know if people will reject me or accept me. Weak point but honest one. About Ghar Wapsi to save Hindu from conversion of the Evangelic I am also informed through the Rss affiliative Swayamsevaks. I totally agree with helping Indians to stay Hindu.

Comment: I hope that my opinion won't bother you. You have my email. ....

Comment: @Mr_Green, read also: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/44078/22667

Comment: Yes. Hinduism is a path, not a destination. Even 'Hindus' can stop following Hinduism if they do not follow its principles. To be accepted in Sanatan community, birth plays an important role, but not the only role. For e.g. ISKCON devotees outside India are overwhelmingly of 'foreign' origin. Sanatan dharma does not differentiate even among species - a bird, animal, rakshas or deva or human - are all equal in terms of eligibility for salvation. Doesn't mean they're equal in terms of duty or path. But in terms of final destination - there is no difference.

Comment: @ram Sita Ram Ram Ram. Jay Shree Ram. This is for you to know the hidden truths https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/44078/22667

Comment: And thank you @ram. I am happy to be accepted as what I know that I am: a Sanataani pure heart.

Comment: yes, one can do so. Please see https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/26326/13287  and https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/26319/13287

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proof of the pudding is in eating. Find out about Sister Nivedita who was a disciple of Swami Vivekananda. Her European name is Margaret Noble. So the answer to your question is a resounding yes.

[image]

A good discussion is in wikipedia.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sister_Nivedita

I am posting some excerpts about Sister Nivedita.

> 'Great things can be done by great sacrifices only!' averred
> Vivekananda. Nivedita - the Dedicated One - his illustrious disciple,
> did exactly that. She sacrificed her people, her country and her
> culture, to devote every breadth of her life for the cause she loved -
> at the command of her Guru, her mentor - serving India and its people.
> She showed Indians how to be truly Indian. She made the Hindus feel a
> few inches taller, by her overflowing love and admiration, for
> Hinduism which she vigorously propagated, a la Vivekananda!
>
> Margaret Elizabeth Noble - that was her original name - was born at
> Dungannon (Ireland) on October 28, 1867. Rev. Samuel Richmond Noble
> and Mary Isabel were her parents. ........
>
> Though she was deeply religious by nature and loved Jesus with all her
> heart, the Christian doctrines of the Church did not satisfy her
> spiritual hunger. Though the life and teachings of the Buddha, which
> she happened to read at that time, brought some solace to her troubled
> soul, the inner turbulence continued, leaving many a question
> unanswered.
>
> It was at this critical juncture of her love that she learnt of the
> arrival of a 'Hindu Yogi' whose discourses and personality had started
> casting a spell as it were, on the Londonites.
>
> Vivekananda visited England twice, the second visit being a much
> larger one. By listening to his talks and getting her doubts cleared
> through searching questions, for which she got scintillating answers,
> Margaret was now fully convinced of Vivekananda's greatness and
> accepted him as her spiritual Master.
>
> One day, when he was talking of his plan of work which included the
> upliftment of Indian women through proper education and training, and
> hinted that she could be of great help in the same, she felt an inner
> urge to accept the call.
>
> ..............
>
> As per the direction of her teacher, she started in her newly acquired
> house in the same area, a school for girls. It was inaugurated by no
> less a person than the Holy Mother herself on the auspicious day (13th
> November 1898), Vivekananda and other members of the Ramakrishna Order
> also being present.
>
> ............
>
> A severe epidemic of plague broke out in Calcutta in March 1899. As
> per the directions of Swami Vivekananda, Nivedita, with the help of
> some Swamis and volunteers, organised relief work excellently, thereby
> earning the gratitude of the people of the city. This was the maiden
> relief work of the Ramakrishna Mission.
>
> ............
>
> Continuous travelling and hard work told upon her frail health. She
> fell seriously ill, once in 1905 and again in 1911. She passed away
> peacefully on the 13th October 1911, at Darjeeling.
>
> The place where her mortal remains were cremated, has a memorial with
> this inscription:
>
> **Here Repose the Ashes of Sister Nivedita (Margaret E. Noble) of the
> Ramakrishna Vivekananda, who gave her all to India. 13 October 1911.**
>
> Nivedita was a prolific writer. There are fifteen books penned by her
> which have been brought out as a set of volumes under the general
> title:
>
> **The Complete Works of Sister Nivedita Vol. I to IV** during her centenary  year (1967). Out of them the two books - **The Master as I
> saw him** and **Notes on some wanderings with the Swami Vivekananda**
>
> - give us a fascinating picture of the great Swami.
>
> If India is free today, the credit for inspiring her national leaders
> of the freedom movement, goes as much to Nivedita as to her guru,
> Swami Vivekananda.

**A Concise Encyclopedia of Hinduism, Volume 2, Swami Harshananda**

[image]

A picture of the girl's school founded by Sister Nivedita

Comment: Dhanyawaad,  Pradip Ji

Comment: @ hindustudent-TheWhiteHindu, You should talk to people like Maria Wirth to find out her views on the issues you have raised. You can find out about her from google.

Comment: It would be more useful if some details about the personality or practice provided :)

Comment: @Pandya, धर्मो रक्षति रक्षितः। means: stop to censor people when they defend the Dharma. Stop to censor them when they admit that Kali Yugic cults are Adharmic. Your moderatorship means this and nothing else. VANDE MATARAM.

Answer (score 1):

..

kirāta-hūṇāndhra-pulinda-pulkaśā
ābhīra-śumbhā yavanāḥ khasādayaḥ
ye 'nye ca pāpā yad-apāśrayāśrayāḥ
śudhyanti tasmai prabhaviṣṇave namaḥ

SYNONYMS
kirāta—a province of old Bhārata; hūṇa—part of Germany and Russia; āndhra—a province of southern India; pulinda—the Greeks; pulkaśāḥ—another province; ābhīra—part of old Sind; śumbhāḥ—another province; yavanāḥ—the Turks; khasa-ādayaḥ—the Mongolian province; ye—even those; anye—others; ca—also; pāpāḥ—addicted to sinful acts; yat—whose; apāśraya-āśrayāḥ—having taken shelter of the devotees of the Lord; —  ; tasmai—unto Him; prabhaviṣṇave—unto the powerful Viṣṇu; namaḥ—my respectful obeisances.

TRANSLATION

Kirāta, Hūṇa, Āndhra, Pulinda, Pulkaśa, Ābhīra, Śumbha, Yavana, members of the Khasa races and even others addicted to sinful acts can be  by taking shelter of the devotees of the Lord, due to His being the supreme power. I beg to offer my respectful obeisances unto Him.

Comment: I do not like the Christian anglican translations. But I thank you to make it clear that if I am not a Snake in this body, and I am not, still I have the right to hope to be accepted by some Hindu communities. I will print your answer as an identity card when I will be in India. Dhanyawaad.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing I believe. Sanatana dharma is a way of life and the whole birth/caste thing has been taken out of context. In the ancient times, a Brahmana was an ascetic who lived a very simple life (very little materialistic attachments or like a nomadic monk) and had a higher plane of thought. In fact if you look at all the hindu mythologies, you will find it riddled with colourful characters that challenge commonly held notions. One of the triumvirates, lord shiva is an interesting character himself. He is believed to cover himself in ashes, has got a snake (which was described by some as a low form of life) around his neck and is believed by some to indulge in smoking cannabis. Could it be any less normal? The first thing you have to remember is that, unlike Abrahamic religions, hinduism does not have a defacto book of sorts that lists out what a hindu should or shouldn't do in terms of strict rules. Infact, krishna himself says in the gita that the all paths ultimately lead to him.

Gita

aham ātmā guḍākeśa sarva bhūtāśaya sthitaḥ |

aham ādiśca madhyaṃ ca bhūtānām anta eva ca || 20 ||

10:20. I am the Self, O Gudakesha (Arjuna —Conqueror-of-sleep), dwelling in the hearts of all beings. I verily am the beginning, the middle and also the end of all beings.

When krishna says that he is the creator,sustainer and destroyer of all beings, why would there be any question as to whether a white or black or asian  person can adhere to sanatana dharma.

Comment: What you write is all wrong, head to toes.  By the way thank you

Comment: Hello ReezaHendricks. Welcome to HSE. We follow strict rule of citing hindu scripture sources always. If possible, please take out some time to add possible sources wherever you feel it can make the answer better. Please also go through FAQ and help page of this site. If any questions, please ask them meta. Or ping me here for any help.

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism Stack Exchange! This looks more like an opinion or comment. We insist on citing some authentic sources while answering questions.

Comment: Gita

aham ātmā guḍākeśa sarva bhūtāśaya sthitaḥ |

aham ādiśca madhyaṃ ca bhūtānām anta eva ca || 20 ||

10:20. I am the Self, O Gudakesha (Arjuna —Conqueror-of-sleep), dwelling in the hearts of all beings. I verily am the beginning, the middle and also the end of all beings.

When krishna says that he is the creator,sustainer and destroyer of all beings, why would there be any question as to whether a white or black or asian person can adhere to sanatana dharma.

Answer (score -1):

Human birth is the most brahmanic birth for a any soul on this earth.
While animals come next to it .
Snake in my opinion is least brahmanic birth and they live in underworld .
Exception to few divine snakes like Lord Adisesha , vasuki who are immortals with purpose and devotion to God . Even they are snakes they attained greatness with devotion to God .
So basically that is more important .

Comment: Ok, so can myself hope to be a snake in my next rebirth? @Aditya Yada?

Comment: It was a joke :D. Maybe.