# Can foreigners become Hindu- Sanatani?

Tags: dharma-shastras

[Can a non-Indian person trust Sanatan Dharma, follow it and so become Hindu?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/44076/22667)

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto That question is closed though, so this person re-asked the question.

Comment: Yeah. I disagree with why they closed it. There is no reason to close this question. Maybe racism? @Ikshvaku

Comment: And @Ikshvaku there is no western dream for me. Only Indian dream. You can not be able to count the number of western ppl heads whose Ego i don't like. Nor you still know me. Have a chance, contact me on my profile given email.

Comment: We will make Hindu Sanatani Rashtra also in Europe one day. Stop Conversion. Mata Ki Jay. @Rickross, and Ikshvaku

Comment: yes. they can - see https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/26326/13287  and https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/26319/13287

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can foreigners become Hindu- Sanatani?

Yes they can. From the Garuda Purana:

> Bhakti or devotion is of eight kinds. If this bhakti is found in a mleccha, he should be considered as a devout and knowing Brahmin. Giving things to him and taking things from him as gifts is proper. He should be treated with the same reverence as I myself (Lord Vishnu).

From the [Mahabharata](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m12/m12a064.htm):

> Indra said, 'The mlecchas should serve their mothers and fathers, their preceptors and other seniors, and recluses living in the woods. The mlecchas should also serve their kings. The duties and rites inculcated in the Vedas should also be followed by them. They should perform sacrifices in honour of the Pitris, dig wells, (and dedicate them to universal service), give water to thirsty travellers, give away beds and make other seasonable presents unto Brahmanas. Abstention from injury, truth, suppression of wrath, supporting Brahmanas and kinsmen by giving them their dues, maintenance of wives and children, purity, peacefulness, making presents to Brahmanas at sacrifices of every kind, are duties that should be practised by every person of this class who desire his own prosperity. Such a person should also perform all kinds of Paka-yajnas with costly presents of food and wealth. These and similar duties, O sinless one, were laid down in olden days for persons of this class. All these acts which have been laid down for all others should also be done by mlecchas, O king.'

Comment: bht dnvd. I never have served the mleccha desha. If u will contact my email i can tell u why i m not a mleccha desha even if myself i was born european in body and geography place. But phisical body is not all in a person. Actually i want indian friends, not other western ones. Actually it is more useful to me to be a Swayamsevak for indians and help them stay Hindu. @Ikshvaku

Comment: Because @Ikshvaku i can not change mleccha desha nature until Krshna Himself do not suggest me to. Despite Shiva suggested me to help the christians, they are mostly helpless. White Hindu are always censored and casted away. I m only asking to consider me an indian.

Comment: Jivaatma does not belong to the appearance physical body.  Mlecchas are in the causal body. Geography may define partially but it is up to aatma. Ask me why I refused the christian baptism? Ask me why people ask me "are you Indian" since my childhood. It is not showing up. Please. It is on: why instead many indians are muslims or christians? Their second body is the problem and not the body that you see in front of you.

Comment: u live in the usa??????????????? https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=EaZ16_UDEuM

Comment: I emailed u thank u @Ikshvaku