# What would be good books to read to learn the basics?

Tags: book-recommendation

I know practically nothing about Hinduism, which is a problem, considering that more than a billion people believe in it. This strongly suggests there's something going for it.

As a curious agnostic, what English-language books would people recommend for me to understand the basics of what Hindus believe and the evidence for the truth of it? Preferably available as E-books or on Kindle, preferably written in a reasonably straightforward style?

Apologies for bothering you with my ignorance. Thanks.

Comment: Hello Bill, Welcome to Hinduism.SE! There is no single philosophical school subscribed to by all the Indian Philosophies. Having said that, the common thread that binds all the various schools of thought in Hinduism is in their relation to the [Vedas](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/774/how-did-the-vedas-in-hinduism-come-into-existence)...1/2

Comment: 2/2...The collection of schools of thought which accept the authority of Vedas are those that constitute [Hindu Philosophy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindu_philosophy). Are you primarily interested in the philosophical aspects of Hinduism?

Comment: Welcome! You might find this post helpful - [Looking to learn about Hinduism](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/17635/looking-to-learn-about-hinduism)

Comment: Thank you, Lakshmi! I'm primarily interested in the question of, "what is it?" I generally think of things in a western, "there is either zero or one correct religion and I want to know which and, if one, what it is" way.

I know that there is this thing called Hinduism, though I may be wrong. I know it is generally considered a religion. I just want to know... what do Hindus believe? Why do they believe it? I know what the Abrahamic faiths hold, can point at miracles and the lack thereof for them. But I don't even know enough to know what I don't know about Hinduism.

Comment: And thank you, Sree! That's not quite my question, but it's close! Following link chains now.