# Where can I learn about Hinduism?

Tags: scripture

I've always had a keen interest in Hindu music. From this liking, I've seen stories such as the churning of the ocean of milk and of Rama and Sita. They are all very archaic and beautiful and so I want to learn more.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Looking to learn about Hinduism?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/17635/looking-to-learn-about-hinduism) and [How to read Hindu Scriptures](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/15693/5212)