# How should I start to learn everything about Sanaatan (Hindu) Dharma and Sanaatan (Hindu) Pauranika stories?

Tags: scripture, sanskrit

I want to know the sequence of reading Sanaatani (Hindu) scriptures to know everything about Sanaatan (Hindu) Dharma. I've heard that translated books often contain misinterpretations and opinions which could lead to deformation of your own opinions. If this so, should I have to learn Sanskrit first?

Comment: [How to read Hindu Scriptures](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/15693/how-to-read-hindu-scriptures)

Comment: [Looking to learn Hinduism](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/17635/looking-to-learn-about-hinduism)

Comment: https://book.gitapress.org/ has one of the most authentic books on sanatana written by Kashi scholars. It ships all over world. There are many English books. If you have particular interests let us know we can suggest accordingly. Yes learning Sanskrit is always great but that's a long road to master and not necessarily required unless you want be scholar.