# Why aren't other religions detailed in Puranas and other scriptures?

Tags: mahabharata, puranas, other-religions, itihasa

Why don't Hindu texts talk much about other religions?

Some people say no other religion existed at the time of Santana Dharma but as per holy books of other religions their religions existed right from the creation of the world.

In Christianity, God created earth and in Islam, Allah was the one who created everything and their religion was from the beginning.

There are only some minor descriptions of other kingdoms as far as Greece (Yavana) mentioned in Mahabharata but again the description is not clear as to who they were, their religion, rituals, etc. There maybe a few minor details here and there about other religions but they don't clearly define them, their rituals and practices.

Comment: see [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/110/does-hinduism-acknowledge-the-existence-of-other-religions) some answers may answer your question

Comment: Bhavishya Purana mentions about other religions as mentioned in the answer by guhan.

Comment: have you considered the possibility that such scriptures could have been destroyed by the very same religion(s)?

Comment: I'm pretty sure Buddhism and Jainism are mentioned, is your question mainly about Abrahamic religions which were founded later?

Comment: I don't think you mean Puranas in specific so I've made some edits to include all Hindu scriptures.

Comment: The question is why doesn't Christianity or Islam talk about Hinduism, when Hinduism is obviously older than both ?

Answer (score 3):

Abrahamic scriptures may not be mentioned explicitly, but the opinion of Vyasa on other scriptures can be inferred,
(All quotes are from Kurma Purana)

Kurma Purana 1.2.54

सर्व लोक विरुद्धं च धर्मं अपि आचरेत न |

One should not follow the Dharma which is against all the people of the world.

Kurma purana1. 12.

O Best of the mountains by means of
meditation, karmayoga devotion (the path of path desireless action) and jñana, I can easily be
achieved, and not by performing of the crores of ritualistic acts.253

The best of dharmas enshrined in the Srutis and Smrties, are also meant for salvation. All of them should be followed with the divine knowledge of self.254

It is from Dharma, Devotion  developes
and with the devotion, one achieves the
Supreme goal viz. Brahman as well as the moksa. The dharma defined in the Srutis and Smritis, has been equated with the yajña.255

One cannot achieve dharma by any other means. The following of the Vedas develops dharma. Therefore those desirous of moksa (ultimate liberation) and dharma should resort to the Vedas which are my embodiment.256

It is my own ancient and supreme potency that is termed as the Vedas. The same takes to the form of Rgveda, Yajurveda, and Sämaveda at the start of the creation.257

For the protection of the same Vedas, Lord Brahma, created the Brähmanas and established them in their respective activities.258

The one who does not recite my dharma, the Tamisra hells of the lower regions has been made for them by Brahmā.259

There is no other scripture, except the Vedas in this world which could establish dharma. A person who devotes to the other scriptures,
discarding the Vedas, the Brähmaņas should have no talk with such peôple.260

Those various scriptures which are against the Srutis and Smrtis seen in this world, are based on Tamo-guna or ignorance and belief or devotion in them is of tâmasika nature.261

All other Sâstras like Käpälas, Bhairavas,Väma, Arhata-Bauddha and Jaina,' etc are simply to create confusion.
262

In another incarnation of(Shiva) mine, these scriptures having been promulgated by me to delude the people who themselves try to mislead other persons by propagating their false scriptures. 263

The people who have well interpreted the Smrtis as activity belonging to the Vedas, have prescribed some karmas to be performed by the people, and the people who perform them, they
are extremely dear to me.264

In order to shower grace on the people of all the Varnas, the Virat Puruşa (great personality), Svāyambhûva Manu himself formerly
promulgated the Code of Dharma to the sages, at my behest.265

The other ascetics also listening to the same dharma from his mouth, further created the Sástras (codes of Dharmas) for the establishment of dharma.266

At the time of the end of the yuga, with the disappearing of the those Sastras, at the command of Brahmā, those Maharşis, continued to compose Sästras in each one of the yugas.267

O King, eighteen major Purăņas were
composed by the sage Vyāsa, at the command of Brahmā, in which the Dharma had been enshrined.268

His disciples composed the Upa-Puräņas. In each and every yuga, those well-versed in the Dharma-Sastras, composed these Upa-Puränas, in every yuga.269

These Sastras are supportive of siksa
(phonetics), kalpa (the rules regarding
rites) Vyákarana(grammer), Nirukta
(Etymology), Chandas (Prosody) Jyotișa (Astrology) and Nyaya-vidyá (Logic), besides expanding them. Thus, O Best of the Brähmanas, these fourteen Sästras are appended
and are linked with the Vedas. Dharma is enshrined in these Sastras and no where else.270, 271

Thus the dharma as established by the grandsire, is continued to be further established by Manu, Vyāsa and others, till the end of the time of dissolution.272

Also its said in 1.15.25 to 31

Dadhīchi, finding the gods and the sages antagonistic to lord Rudra, said to Dakşa,
"A person earns enormous sin by neglecting adoration of the adorable person and adoring of
the undesirable deities. There is no doubt about it.
Where the people with falsehood are respected and the noble people are humiliated, there the punishing rod of the destiny surely falls."

"Thus speaking, the said Rishi Dadhīcha, pronounced a curse on the Brāhmanas, who had arrived there and were envious of Siva.
Because you have driven out Paramesvara from the prescribed Vedic practices and have particularly humiliated lord Siva who is adored by the universe, therefore all of you shall fall from the Vedic path Trayi (three ) Vedas prescribed by lord Siva."

"Those of the people under the influence of the false scriptures, their studies as well as their conduct and human behaviour shall be falsified. Even otherwise those possessing the false knowledge, reaching the age of terrific Kaliyuga shall have to suffer from all the sides."

Comment: Aren't all modern religions by their very nature from Viṣṇuyaśas, the only God who has proof of his existence everywhere you go? The major religions also imply this same concept. Even atheists and false prophets can't escape the control of Viṣṇuyaśas, who shows the truth by their failings.

Comment: @Krsna Dasa Hare Krsna and Thank you for this very complete answer! Jaya Jaya Jaya Hanuman!

Comment: @Aupakarana Abhibhaa I am Italian. So obviously I was born in a christian society. I can grant you that the relationship with God who the christian have is of Terror and Fear. This is Not the same Theology of Sanatan Dharma. This last gives the instruction to us humans to overcome our fragilities and fears and emotion. While Bhagavad Geeta is THE way to approach to Ultimate Reality, the Bible is obscure, contradictory, wicking at times, and very strange as a book. Plus its Vulgata rendered the text already corrupted also in its translations.

Comment: You can read: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/44078/22667 to have more informations about why I left christianity.

Answer (score 1):

Who said so,
In the bhavishya purana 3.3.5 it is mentioned:
after this the king was accompanied by mleccha dharma teacher known as muhammad.
bhavishya purana 3.3.24: here prophet muhammed accepts his religion mlecha.

Comment: your answer is not properly readable, please reformat it, and if possible add citations.

Answer (score 1):

They are. Probably the most fun time this happens is with the four horses of the Four Horsemen of the Apocalypse from Christianity in the Bhaviṣya Purāṇa:

https://www.pdfdrive.com/bhavishya-purana-bhavishya-maha-purana-pratisarg-parv-khand-three-full-translated-to-english-d179134516.html

Okay, Muhammed, Jesus, etc. might be more important revelations, but finding out the backstory of the horses is the most fun of the short stories. I always wanted to know more about the backstories of the animals in scripture.

P.S. I wonder if the fact Christianity and Islam are both referenced twice in the section I gave a link to has any deeper meaning to it.