# With which Devata is Gabriel (or Jibril) related?

Tags: scripture, vedas

Devatas and Angels are same. Only names are different.

Gabriel or Jibril are called Archangel, the chief angel, therefore I guess Gabriel or Jibril is Lord Brahma or Indra. But I am not sure.

Are there any evidence on which Devata is or related to Gabriel (or Jibril)?

Comment: There is no evidence for this.The Only evidence is that Lord Shiva will propagate false scriptures in this age of Kali. Abrahamic religions are basically religion of this Kali Yuga. Only good thing about them is that they believe in a God who has created this universe or their belief in a kingdom of God, the rest of their philosophy is based on the bodily concept of life which is not transcendental. https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/42673/why-arent-other-religions-detailed-in-puranas-and-other-scriptures/43374#43374

Comment: Hi! I created a chatroom for this. Please check it out if you want to discuss in detail.

Comment: Abrahamic religions are recent new religion of Kaliyuga, before them Greek, Persian and Egyptian culture were present and disappeared, Sanatan is eternal. They are given concept of Hell and Heaven, because these are mainly varnaless random Rajsik-Tamsik races and incompetent to understand the subtle concept of Atman or Brahman unlike Satvik Hindus. If Hinduism is post-graduation based on Puranas, Vedas, Abrahamic religions are primary class. They are pirated version of Hinduism like Brahma-Saraswati is Abraham-Sara, Vishnu is Jesus, Manu is Noah, saptrishi are seven angels, Brahman is Allah.

Comment: There is no concept like this exists before Kaliyuga (Abrahamic are false religion). Abrahamic and Sanatan religion has no common field. Neither do our scripture tell us about Jesus or other stuff. If you think about `bhavishya Purana` it is not an accurate translation. Also, Sanatan Dharma is much older than those Abrahamic concepts. Abrahamic Concept is greatly inspired by Avesta (Iranian religion). Avesta is a false and corrupted copy of rig Vedas. As few Hymns are similar. In Avesta, `There is mention of Lord Ram`. http://www.hindupedia.com/en/Zoroastrianism_and_Hinduism

Comment: Dear Krsna dasa, thank you so much. I asked this question because if I get the information about relation between devata and Jibril, then Muslim people would feel more intimate to Vedic culture in preaching activities. But it's all right there is no evidence. It's sure someone devata taught Dharma to Muammad.

Comment: Dear Manu Kumar, thank you so much. I wish somehow I could encourage Muslim people to read Srimad Bhagavatam and to chant the holy name of the Lord expertly.

Comment: @Radhikadasi  this explanation by Suhotra Swami Maharaj can be of use to you.   https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=7LmVdAgM-uc

Comment: Dear Krsna prabhu, wow, it is great (^_^)v  I really appreciate your help. Thank you so much.

Comment: Great answers, nothing to add! 