# Does any Āstika text mention Gunas association with the Adharmic cults?

Tags: puranas, dharma-shastras, gunas, yoga-sutras

Someone said that Abrahmic cults are associated with Gunas [Tamoguna for Islam and Rajaguna for Christianity].
This information I have read was not documented by any Shastras quotation.

So I want to ask if is that true, and where to find mention of that in Shastras or eventually Samhkya evaluable texts or others Āstika texts.

Comment: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/42673/why-arent-other-religions-detailed-in-puranas-and-other-scriptures/43374#43374                                "Those various scriptures which are against the Srutis and Smrtis seen in this world, are based on Tamo-guna or ignorance and belief or devotion in them is of tâmasika nature."  Kurma Purana

Comment: @Krsna Dasa thank you

Comment: I think all abrahamic religions are combination of Rajo and Tamo Guna as its a sign of Kali Yuga. Also, Swami Chinmayananda in 18th chapter  His commentary Holy Geeta refers fanatic followers and missionaries as Rajasic. I don't remember what He said about Tamasic followers.

Comment: Thank you so much @RishX

Comment: The most ancient surviving Vedic tradition cannot comment on 
 Abrahamic religions which came much later on. But later followers of Hinduism can identify which aspects differ from the tenets of Adharma (violence,untruth, injustice)..

Comment: Why call them "cults"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From Manu Smriti:

> 12.95. All those traditions (smriti) and those despicable systems of philosophy, which are not based on the Veda, produce no reward after
> death; **for they are declared to be founded on Darkness**.
>
> 12.96. All those (doctrines), differing from the (Veda), which spring up and (soon) perish, are worthless and false, because they are of
> modern date.

"for they are declared to be founded on Darkness" --- Here darkness refers to Tamas. So, all doctrines and religious philosophies that are in contradiction with the Vedas are criticized here as Tamasik. But we don't expect specific Abrahamic religions to be mentioned in scriptures like Manu Smriti.

Comment: thank you. Let me add something here: